# SQL Server 2017 Nested Insert or using results of one insert in another insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, sql-insert

My problem can be summarized with the following contrived example.
I have several tables:

```
AUTOMOBILE
AutoId Make Model Color

BATCH
BatchId SaleDate

INVENTORY
InventoryId AutoId BatchId CustomerName(string) ParkingSlipId

PARKING
ParkingSlipId SlipStatus(String)
```

Currently, there are no rows in the INVENTORYtable or BATCH table.  I would like to, with a query or stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, create some fake data in INVENTORY.  To do this, I will simply take the first 10 rows of AUTOMOBILE table and use the AutoId from AUTOMOBILE as INVENTORY.AutoId.  I also need to create a new row in BATCH for each entry in INVENTORY. I'll use the BATCH.BatchId as INVENTORY.BatchId.   CustomerName can for now, just be the word "Fred". For the ParkingSlipId, I can take any row from PARKING where the SlipStatus is "Empty" and use that ParkingSlipId and change the status to "Full".

I've played around with this problem with limited success.  I can for instance use something like:

```
INSERT  [BATCH] 
VALUES (GETDATE())   
DECLARE @tempLoadBatchId bigint
 SELECT @tempLoadBatchId = @@IDENTITY
```

I can the use tempLoadBatchId in my next insert (into INVENTORY)

```
    INSERT  [INVENTORY] (AutoId BatchId CustomerName ParkingSlipId)
VALUES (3,  @tempLoadBatchId, "Fred",77);

UPDATE [PARKING] set SlipStatus= 'FullBoat' where SlipId = 77
```

Notice this is just for one row AND I simply hardcoded the AutoId.

I'd like to automate this.  Using Cursors seems one way to do it, and that's certainly an option (these are tiny tables and the performance won't be an issue) but I'd also like to know how to do it without cursors.
Thanks, Dave

**MORE BACKGROUND AND DESIRED RESULTS**
In response to comments, I've added some more info.  I can backup and attach the entire DB if that's of use.  I assume StackOverflow will allow that.

Here is the current AUTO table

```
AutoId  Make    Model   Colour
1   Ford    Taurus  White
2   GM  Cadilac Silver
3   Toyota  Prius   Blue
4   Honda   Pilot   Green
5   Kia Sonata  Yellow
```

Here is the current PARKING Table

ParkingSlipId    SlipStatus
   1    Empty
   2    Empty
   3    Empty
   4    Empty
   5    Empty
   6    Empty
   7    Empty
   8    Empty

For each row in AUTO, I would like to create a new entry in BATCH, and then use that BatchId to create a new INVENTORY entry.  In that new INVENTORY entry, I'd like to use the row from AUTO and assign a parkingId and change the corresponding parkingid in PARKING TO FULL.  When all this is done, the tables BATCH, INVENTORY, and PARKING should look like:

```
PARKING
ParkingSlipId   SlipStatus
 1  Full      
2   Full      
3   Full      
4   Full      
5   Full      
6   Empty     
7   Empty     
8   Empty     

BATCH
BatchId SaleDate
  1 2018-09-15 00:00:00.000
2   2018-08-20 00:00:00.000
3   2018-06-22 00:00:00.000
4   2018-09-12 00:00:00.000
5   2018-07-01 00:00:00.000


INVENTORY
InventoryId AutoId  BatchId ParkingId   CustomerName
1   1   1   1   Fred
2   2   2   2   Mary
3   3   3   3   Fred
4   4   4   4   Ted
5   5   5   5   James
```

Is there more info I can provide?  Or in a different format?  Many thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Can you include sample data? Hard to say how best to automate it without knowing what we're working with. Regardless, doing this with set based operations rather than row-by-row (i.e. a cursor) is what I'd look into.

Comment: Read about `output` clause in `insert` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution to the problem posed.  However, I use "cursor", something I was trying to avoid.  I'd be interested in set based operations as Xedni suggested in

```
    /****** Script  ******/

DECLARE @tempLoadBatchId bigint
DECLARE @tempAutoId int
DECLARE @tempParkingId int
DECLARE @counter bigint
SET @counter = 0

--- AUTOMOBILE STUFF
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
SELECT AutoId
FROM [CarExample].[dbo].[AUTOMOBILE] 

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tempAutoId

--- PARKING stuff
DECLARE curParking CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ParkingSlipId
FROM [CarExample].[dbo].[PARKING] where SlipStatus = 'Empty' 

OPEN curParking
FETCH NEXT FROM curParking INTO @tempParkingId
-----
WHILE @counter < 10
BEGIN
    INSERT  [CarExample].[dbo].[BATCH] 
     VALUES (GETDATE())   
    SELECT @tempLoadBatchId = @@IDENTITY

    INSERT  CarExample.[dbo].INVENTORY (AutoId, BatchId, ParkingId, CustomerName)
VALUES (@tempAutoId, @tempLoadBatchId, @tempParkingId, 'Sally');
    SET @counter = @counter + 1

UPDATE [CarExample].[dbo].[PARKING] Set SlipStatus = 'Full' where ParkingSlipId = @tempParkingId
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tempAutoId 
FETCH NEXT FROM curParking INTO @tempParkingId
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
CLOSE curParking
DEALLOCATE curParking
```